# Sharedobject in BackGrounde Worker as3 Air (android,ios)

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, air, storage

im Developing an Air app for android and ios and im using workers too preform a heavy task in background (two swfs),i want to have SharedObjects in the worker swf(the background worker) ,is this possible ? or the data will be lost?

Comment: If in doubt, use primary thread to interact with data that should be stored. I don't remember there be any restriction on SharedObjects and workers, but had never tried testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you need to write to the same SharedObject is to specify the same `path` for both like

```
mySO = SharedObject.getLocal("myObjectFile","/");
```

more info here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d80.html

Here is a short code to make you sure that data won't be lost, workers are actually doing the same stuff as multiple flash players ran simultaneously. Just run 2 or more swf and see the result:

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
var iterations:int = 100

function witeToSo()
{
    var mySO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myObjectFile", "/");

    if (iterations > 0)
    {
        if (!mySO.data.str) mySO.data.str = ""

        mySO.data.str += int(Math.random() * 10);   

        iterations--;
    }
    txt.text = "str: " + mySO.data.str + " symbolsTotal:" + (mySO.data.str.length) + "\n";

    setTimeout(witeToSo, Math.random()*100);
}

setTimeout(witeToSo, 2000);
```

Also you need to think of how to synchronise your threads in case you want to write the data in specific order